# Warning messages are displaying even after the data present in the input field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6, angular-forms

I have a component used to display some data (i,e first name, last name, phone ....etc) from the **api**. In order to perform CRUD operation specially **update** operation,.
As in below image:

[image]

> I am facing an issue, when I click **SAVE** button even the data present in the **input field(i,e phone)**. It's is still showing the warning messages(i,e mat-error). As in below image:

[image]

Below is my component code

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm">

      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstname" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="editForm.controls.firstname.hasError('required')">
            Please enter first name
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput  placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastname" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="editForm.controls.lastname.hasError('required')">
            Please enter last name
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field class="phone-number">
          <input matInput placeholder="Phone Number" formControlName="phonenumber" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="editForm.controls.phonenumber.hasError('required')">
            Please enter phone number
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="editForm.controls.phonenumber.hasError('pattern')">
            Please enter a valid phone number
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-sec">
        <button mat-flat-button  type="button" >Cancel</button>
        <button mat-flat-button  type="submit" (click)="onEditForm()">Save</button>
      </div>

   <form>
```

**TS**

```
import{ Component, Inject, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import{ FormBuilder, FormControl ,FormGroup, Validators}fro'@angular/forms';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
import {IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';


@Component({
  selector: 'wsd-update-customer',
  templateUrl: './wsd-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wsd-customer.component.css'],
})

export class EditCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

 public editForm: FormGroup;

constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: IContact,
          private fb: FormBuilder,
          public dialog: MatDialog) {} 

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.editForm = this.fb.group({
    firstname: [ null, [Validators.required],
    lastname: [null, [Validators.required],
    phonenumber: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')]],
   });

this.editForm.get('firstname').setValue(this.data.firstName);
this.editForm.get('lastname').setValue(this.data.lastName);
this.editForm.get('phonenumber').setValue(this.data.phoneNumbers[0].number);
}

 public onEditForm(): void {
   this.markAsDirty(this.editForm);
 }


 private markAsDirty(group: FormGroup): void {
    group.markAsDirty();
     for (const i in group.controls) {
      group.controls[i].markAsDirty();
   }
  }

}
```

**models.ts** file

```
export interface IContact {
  firstName:  string;
  lastName:   string;
   phoneNumbers:  IPhoneNumber[];
 }

 export interface IPhoneNumber {
  type:        string;
  number:      string;
 }
```

**JSON**

```
 {
    "firstName": "Adaline",
   "lastName": "Danat",
   "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "type": "Home",
        "number": "+62 342 886 8201"
      },
      {
        "type": "Business",
        "number": "+63 704 441 1937"
      },
      {
        "type": "Unknown",
        "number": "+63 530 693 2767"
      }
   ],

}
```

**Updated Photo**

[image]

Updated [Stckblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q69nxd-j63htm?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Since it is an `editable form` and if the user makes any of the input field empty`( say first name)`. Then it should show warning message that the input filed`(i,e first name )` is empty.

Comment: But `firstname` and `lastname` are also required fields they are not throwing error .

Comment: @Shankarguru is this same validation for mobile no has applied while creating a customer?

Comment: Ya this validation applies.

Comment: Are you sure this `Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')` is correct?

Comment: Try `updateValueAndValidity()` after `setValue()`

Comment: Let me try your answer.@sabithpocker

Comment: Ya the pattern is correct.@mika

Comment: Still the same issue continuous...:)@sabithpocker

Comment: try this pattern '\+[0-9]+'

Comment: Stackblitz Example will help!

Comment: I am fetching from an `api` @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Sorry it didn't helped..@LucaTaccagni

Comment: It is definitely coming from phone validaton pattern. As the message for pattern validation is being shown. `'[0-9]+'` this pattern doesnt support spaces or `+`.

Comment: @Shankarguru have a look at:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q69nxd

Comment: It's not throwing 
any error!

Comment: Let my try ur **stackblitz example**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you explain why we want to define **new FormControl**  ? on for `phonenumber`.@PrashantPimpale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with the combination of [`FormGroup`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) and [`FormControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) where FormGroup accept an object of [`AbstractControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) Class.

So if you are using FormGroup then it accepts the parameter called `controlsConfig` which describes:

*@param **controlsConfig** A collection of child controls. The key for each child is the name under which it is registered*

So just define the FormGroup with FormControls and add the validation and default value as to the particular Control:

```
this.editForm = this.fb.group({
      firstname: new FormControl([null, [Validators.required]]),
      lastname: new FormControl([null, [Validators.required]]),
      phonenumber: new FormControl([null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')]]),
});
```

**EDIT:**

To assign the value of formControl in a `p`, `span` that is except input type, there are three ways to do this

1) With using Two-way data binding on data itself like:

```
<p>{{data.email}}</p>
```

2) By using FormControl:

```
<p>{{editForm.value.email}}</p>
```

but for this, you have to define a FormControl in the TS file and use setValue to assign the value.

```
email: new FormControl([null])  // define a control in the group

this.editForm.get('email').setValue(this.data.email); // set value from data object
```

3) You use the FormContol with [`readonly`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) attribute

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <input matInput  placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" readonly>
</mat-form-field>
```

[Working StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q69nxd)

Comment: In the same example i want display one more value called `email`  using an `paragraph` not using `input field` as in the **Updated photo**. How to do this. Please edit in Updated **stackblitz link**

Comment: @Shankarguru done, check once! [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q69nxd)

Comment: I know to display using **value**, can i display using **formcontrol** name??

Comment: Are you assign the value In ts file?

Comment: Ya i have assigned in **ts** file check it once.

Comment: @Shankarguru Have edited stackBlitz, have a [look](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q69nxd)

Comment: @Shankarguru is this helped?

Comment: No it didn't helped.

Comment: Like edit i am displaying only `first name` in another form, there i just want to display the `first name`, no validation required.

Comment: I can able display the `first name` but unable assign `first name` to an variable. Because from that `variable` i am sending form data(i,e first name) for performing http DELETE.

Comment: @Shankarguru not clear to me! Can you please elaborate?